# How to show h:message based on condition?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, validation, multilingual

I am making multi-language website where I am using Validator for one field.

After validation, I receive response as `err002, err003` and based on this error I would be showing the respective error in message format. So what I was planning is something like below.

What I have is `<h:message for="password">`

What I wanted to do is as below.

```
if (message is err002) {
    show message of err002 from the properties file.
    #{msg['err002']}
}
if (message is err003) {
    show message of err003 from the properties file.
    #{msg['err003']}
}
```

Any idea how to get this done?

Actually what I want to do is display error message in both language. What I have is language code in session bean, but I can't check language code in validators.

Any idea/ suggestion how this can be done would be greatful.

---

### Edit 1

**faces-config.xml**

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>zh_CN</default-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>resources.welcome</base-name>
        <var>msg</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

**LanguageBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "language")
@SessionScoped
public class LanguageBean implements Serializable {
```

Properties files that I have are

**welcome.properties** and **welcome_zh_CN.properties**

Comment: You can access that session bean, maybe [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html?m=1#AccessingAnotherManagedBean) you will find some idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achive it in a validator method. Use it like

```
@FacesValidator("passwordValidator")
public class PasswordValidator implements Validator {

    String err1, err2, err3;

    public PasswordValidator() {
        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("msg", FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale());
        err1 = bundle.getString("err1");
        err2 = bundle.getString("err2");
        err3 = bundle.getString("err3");
    }

    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        String pass = (String) value;
        FacesMessage msg;
        if(/*some condition*/) {
            msg = new FacesMessage(err1);
        } else if(/*other condition*/) {
            msg = new FacesMessage(err2);
        } else {
            msg = new FacesMessage(err3);
        }
        if(msg != null) {
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }
    }    
}
```

And use it in view with

```
<h:inputText id="password" validator="passwordValidator" .../>
<h:message for=password .../>
```

Comment: I forgot exception throwing - added it just for the case)

Comment: thats great... I will check and get back to you incase of any queries. :) :) I think you will save me...

Comment: There may be two reasons for that. 1. There is no file msg_zh_CN.properties. 2. The bundle is not there where you search for it. Look at the loader method [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).

Comment: that problem is solved, but got new problem as `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale()` always gives me `zh_CN`

Comment: Thanks for code correction. It always happens when writing code without IDE). But please stop removing your input, be consisent!

Comment: any idea why I am getting `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale()` as `zh_CN` only?

Comment: is it because, validator are not managed bean and setting locale is in managed bean?

Comment: above problem is also solved. I moved constructor code to validate method and all worked...

Comment: The `context.addMessage()` line is unnecessry. JSF will already get it from the caught `ValidatorException`.

Comment: Thanks, @BalusC. The redundant line is removed.